# Viewing an inserted link in markdown cell in jupyter notebook as a .HTML file

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I insert a link in a cell using the syntax text and save the notebook as a .html, and open the .html in Chrome, the link is no longer displayed correctly and it shows instead the raw string `[text](URL)`. Why does it happen, and what can be done to display the hyperlink correctly?

Example code: I write in a markdown cell

```
<div style="direction:rtl">
[مرجع](http://www.google.com)
</div>
```

I use the latest version of Jupyter.

Comment: Could you post your code? Do you have any extensions installed? What version of Jupyter are you running? I ask this because I just tried the same thing (have a link formatted as `[text](url)` in markdown cell) and when I convert to HTML it works fine

Comment: @LouiseDavies The problem is when I put the link inside a  `<div style="direction:rtl">
` tag to make the link appear right-to-left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're encountering what is documented in [this issue here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/45). If you put markdown inside HTML then nbconvert will ignore it. You can get around this by just using HTML style url tags

```
<div style="direction:rtl">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">مرجع</a>
</div>
```

This displays correctly both in the live notebook and in converted HTML.